# Derivative of error function and relationship between cumulative distribution function and error function

Tags: calculus

[image]

to my understand for part a), the derivative is simply replacing $t$ with x by the first fundamental theorem of calculus then computing erf'(3) into $1/ sqrt(pi) * exp(-x^2)$

for part b) however, I am not sure if what I have is correct. Since the question states $x >= 0$ , the only possible relationship between CDF and erf(x) I can think of is $Φ(x) = 1/2 (1+ erf(x/sqrt(2))$. Am I on the right track?

edit: this is what i obtained - not sure if this is correct
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is   random variable with distribution $\Phi$ then, for $x \geq 0$, $P\{X\leq x\}=P\{X\leq 0\}+P\{0<X \leq x\}=\frac 1 2 +\int_0^{x}\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-t^{2} /2} \, dt$. To see its connection with the the formula for erf note that $erf(x)=\frac 2 {\sqrt 2\pi}\int_0^{x} e^{-t^{2} /2} \, dt$. So $P\{X\leq x\}=\frac 1 2 [1+erf (x)]$.

Comment: so is my connection correct or not? im struggling to understand what you're trying to tell me

Comment: would the connection be $ 1/2(1 +2 erf(x)) $ ?

Comment: @lohboys I have edited the answer.